# How to generate 10 numbers, either 0 or 1, with six 1's at most?

Tags: matlab

I want to generate 10 numbers which can be either 0 or 1 such that there are six 1's at most and the rest are 0's.

How to do this?

Comment: Can you give a little more info? Are you looking for floats in between like `0.47` also, or just 0 and 1?

Comment: i want just 0 and 1

Comment: Then just generate random numbers. If the number is greater than 0.4, choose 1 otherwise choose 0.

Comment: To get the 60% probability, do you want to generate 10 random numbers where 6 of the 10 are 1 and the rest are 0 ?  That changes things entirely, but is an easily solvable problem.

Comment: To generate ones with 60% probability doesn't mean that you'd necessarily get 6 ones out of 10. It could even result in getting all ones or even all zeros. What do you mean by maximum six 1's? What is the minimum? zero 1's?

Comment: `A = rand(10,1)<0.6`

Comment: Instead of clarification, you deleted the comments in which you told to get maximum 6 ones. If anything, it results in getting irrelevant answers

Comment: actually i want either six 1's or less than six 1's out of 10 random numbers in an array  and the rest are 0

Comment: @david If you actually want to limit the number of 1s you get in the array, you could redo `rand()` until you find an array that conforms to that. I've edited my answer to include the code for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `round(rand(10,1)+0.1)`.

Calling `rand(10,1)` will give you 10 real numbers that range from 0 to 1; add 0.1 to shift the expected mean to 0.6, then round what you get to obtain only 0s or 1s.

If you actually want to cap the number of 1s you get in your array, you could just retry the `rand()` operation until you get six or less 1s:

```
num_sixes = 10;

while num_sixes > 6
    numbers = round(rand(10,1)+0.1);
    num_sixes = sum(numbers);
end

numbers % this will contain at most six 1s
```

Comment: sir actually i want this type of array either  1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 (where no. of 1's  is 6) or 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 (where no. of 1's is 3 i.e. less than 6) but not like this 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 (where no. of 1's is seven)

Comment: Have you tried the code? It does what you're asking for. The array will be stored in `numbers`.

Comment: yes sir i tried the above code but it was not executed

Comment: You just need to type `numbers` in the command line or in the script. I've updated the code in my answer to have it display the array.

Comment: This can result in declined performance if a lot of numbers are to be generated

Comment: It all depends on OP's use case - since he hasn't given us more information (i.e. whether or not he wants to extend this to use more numbers), I have to assume that he would only be using 10 numbers.

Comment: A question is meant to be a minimal example of the problem and a solution is to take care of all cases in general. We have to make posts useful for all the future visitors as well (not just a particular single individual).

Answer (score -1):

Initialise required matrix with [zeros](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html). Then use [`randi`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) to generate the number of 1's you'd be getting and [`randperm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) to get random indices for those 1's. Finally use [matrix indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) to replace 0's at those indices to 1.

```
N = 10;                %Total numbers to be generated
max1s = 6;             %Maximum number of 1s
ReqNum = zeros(N,1);   %Initialising with 0's
idx_of_1s = randperm(N, randi([1 max1s],1,1)); %Generating maximum 'max1s' indices for 1's
ReqNum(idx_of_1s) = 1; %Changing 0's at those indices to 1's
```